# SQL Removing Duplicate Result with Left Join

Tags: sql, group-by, duplicates, distinct

I've got code that if pulling info from two different tables, and I'm getting duplicates. I've tried DISTINCT in the SELECT statement, but I get lots of errors "ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable."

So my next attempt was to try GROUP BY, but I get errors "Column Person.Pers_FirstName is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So my records have multiple relationship fields, but it's a problem because some records have none, one or more than one relationship (the options are NULL, project engineer, project owner, or project contractor). Current code only shows NULL and Project Engineer, but if there's records with the other two then they are excluded. If I include the other relationship descriptions then I get duplicates.

```
SELECT 
    RTRIM(ISNULL(Pers_FirstName, '')) + ' ' + RTRIM(ISNULL(Pers_LastName, '')) AS        Pers_FullName, 
    RTRIM(ISNULL(oppocomp.Comp_PhoneCountryCode, '')) + ' ' + RTRIM(ISNULL(oppocomp.Comp_PhoneAreaCode, '')) + ' ' + RTRIM(ISNULL(oppocomp.Comp_PhoneNumber, '')) AS Comp_PhoneFullNumber,
    RTRIM(ISNULL(oppocomp.Comp_FaxCountryCode, '')) + ' ' + RTRIM(ISNULL(oppocomp.Comp_FaxAreaCode, '')) + ' ' + RTRIM(ISNULL(oppocomp.Comp_FaxNumber, '')) AS Comp_FaxFullNumber, 
    RTRIM(ISNULL(Pers_PhoneCountryCode, '')) + ' ' + RTRIM(ISNULL(Pers_PhoneAreaCode, '')) + ' ' + RTRIM(ISNULL(Pers_PhoneNumber, '')) AS Pers_PhoneFullNumber, 
    RTRIM(ISNULL(Pers_FaxCountryCode, '')) + ' ' + RTRIM(ISNULL(Pers_FaxAreaCode, '')) + ' ' + RTRIM(ISNULL(Pers_FaxNumber, '')) AS Pers_FaxFullNumber, 
    Opportunity.*, oppocomp.Comp_Name, oppocomp.Comp_Territory, oppocomp.Comp_EmailAddress,
    oppocomp.Comp_CompanyId, oppocomp.Comp_SecTerr, oppocomp.Comp_CreatedBy,
    oppocomp.Comp_PrimaryUserID, Terr_Caption, Pers_Title, Pers_EmailAddress, Pers_SecTerr,
    Pers_CreatedBy, Pers_PersonId, Pers_PrimaryUserID, Chan_Description,
    oppocomp.Comp_ChannelID, (Oppo_Base_Currency.Curr_CurrencyID) AS Oppo_WeightedForecast_CID,
    Pers_ChannelID ((Oppo_Forecast / Oppo_Forecast_Currency.Curr_Rate) * Oppo_Certainty / 100) AS Oppo_WeightedForecast, 
    Oppo_PrimaryAccountId AS Acc_AccountId, rend_Notes, renl_description,
    relcomp.Comp_Name AS Rela_CompanyName 
FROM Opportunity 
LEFT JOIN Person ON Oppo_PrimaryPersonID = Pers_PersonID 
LEFT JOIN Company AS oppocomp ON Oppo_PrimaryCompanyID = Comp_CompanyId 
LEFT JOIN Territories ON Oppo_SecTerr = Terr_TerritoryId 
LEFT JOIN Channel ON Chan_ChannelId = Oppo_ChannelId 
LEFT JOIN RelatedEntityData ON Oppo_OpportunityId = rend_entity1id 
LEFT JOIN RelatedEntityLinks ON rend_relatedentitylinkid = REnL_RelatedEntityLinkID 
LEFT JOIN Company AS relcomp ON rend_entity2id = relcomp.Comp_CompanyId 
LEFT JOIN Currency Oppo_Forecast_Currency ON Oppo_Forecast_CID = Oppo_Forecast_Currency.Curr_CurrencyID 
LEFT JOIN Currency Oppo_Base_Currency 
     ON Oppo_Base_Currency.Curr_CurrencyID = (
                SELECT CAST(CAST(Parm_Value AS NCHAR) AS INTEGER) 
                  FROM Custom_SysParams
                 WHERE Parm_Name = 'BaseCurrency'
            ) 
WHERE Oppo_Deleted IS NULL
  AND (renl_description IS NULL OR renl_description = 'Project Engineer')
```

Comment: If you were doing a group by <Column1..Column N>, you can only have these columns and aggregates in the select list. Hence the error saying column is invalid in select list.

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: It's a SQL we're running on our CRM. I'm trying to group it by the description of the opportunity. Oh and BTW, total noob here.